# mySQL Trigger After INSERT, Insert a row in another table, reference both rows

Tags: mysql, database-trigger

Let's say i have 2 tables.

1. Table A
2. Table B

In Table A i created a trigger that runs "AFTER Insert", in this trigger i Insert a row into Table B, containing a reference to Table A, with this i made another Trigger in Table B, "AFTER Insert" i got the inserted id on Table B and with the reference to Table A i tried to Update Table A's Row with a reference to Table B.

This however wasn't possible because it triggers this problem:

> Can't update table in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger

I tried checking out this problem in SO already but, no other case seemed appliable to this problem. How can i get around this?

TLDR:
I just want a trigger that when a new row is inserted create another row in another table and reference them both with a foreign id in both tables.

Comment: Can you describe what you are trying to do (at the moment you are presenting a 'problem' with your solution)?

Comment: My solution is not working because i get the error presented above, im trying to automatically using triggers create a row in another table, in that row pass a reference of the first table, and then after that one is create pass a reference to the 1st row added of the 2nd row.

Comment: Your solution is not working because it's not workable. You can create a trigger on table a to update table be and pass NEW. values to b on an insert but you cannot create a trigger on b to update a. You need to add a more articulate question than 'after that one is create pass a reference to the 1st row added of the 2nd row. '

Comment: Why is that not possible though?
Is there a reason for this, or is it just not a supported function, because i can create a trigger that updates another table but that trigger cannot be triggered by the table that is going to be updated even if it's an already inserted row, why is this?

Comment: Because you could generate an infinite loop and the developers can’t seem to figure out a way round this. There may be a different approach but you would have to ask a better question.